# Undefined reference to `pantheios_init`

Tags: c++, g++, pantheios

I'm trying to use pantheios, I read this tutorial -> http://binglongx.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/pantheios-logging-library-installation-and-use/

The *make build* and *make test* are ok, I got a lot of "success"

But when i try to include this files, i got some errors

```
#include <pantheios/pantheios.hpp>
#include <pantheios/inserters/integer.hpp>
#include <pantheios/inserters/pointer.hpp>
```

**errors :**

```
/tmp/ccuzd4cD.o: In function `pantheios_initialiser::pantheios_initialiser()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN21pantheios_initialiserC1Ev[pantheios_initialiser::pantheios_initialiser()]+0xd): undefined reference to `pantheios_init'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN21pantheios_initialiserC1Ev[pantheios_initialiser::pantheios_initialiser()]+0x1e): undefined reference to `pantheios_exitProcess'
/tmp/ccuzd4cD.o: In function `pantheios_initialiser::~pantheios_initialiser()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN21pantheios_initialiserD1Ev[pantheios_initialiser::~pantheios_initialiser()]+0xd): undefined reference to `pantheios_uninit'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

STLSOFT is ok.

**g++ compilation**

```
g++ src/main.cpp -Wall -I./stlsoft-1.9.112/include -I./pantheios-1.0.1-beta213/include  -L./pantheios-1.0.1-beta213/lib -o test
```

My gcc version is : gcc version 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8), I build the *gcc44.unix* directory.

I'm using the *pantheios-1.0.1-beta213* (lastest)

Is it a link error ?

Comment: Seems you are failing to link against pantheios' lib.

Comment: Indeed, i found the way to compile : http://qtcast.googlecode.com/svn-history/r25/trunk/deps/pantheios/FAQ.txt The Q&A13